# Change string (f. E. 6,6) to float

Tags: python-3.x

I like to change a datatype of a column from a table. 
This are the existing datatypes

```
-Data columns (total 7 columns):
-Nr.               30267 non-null int64
-Tag               30267 non-null object
-Datum             30267 non-null object
-Uhrzeit           30267 non-null object
-Mst01 [cm]        30267 non-null object
-Mst01 [l/s]       30267 non-null object
-(Kommentar) []    30267 non-null object
```

I like to change the Mst01 [cm] and Mst01 [l/s] from string to float. 
The code below should solve the problem, but pandas can not change the datatype.

```
#Tab = Tab['Mst01 [cm]'].astype(float) #######
```

This is the errormessage, i dont know why the error occure.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6,6'
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please provide an excerpt of `Tab` dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python assumes that the decimal separator is `.`. You are trying to convert a string that uses `,` as a decimal separator. Do a `replace` command on your dataframe first:

```py
Tab['Mst01 [cm]'] = Tab['Mst01 [cm]'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! I think pandas can handle the ",".